# regular expression matching for [ ]

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex expression
[a-zA-Z- \d )( / . ]

which matches my requirements but i want it to match [] this brackets too.

It should match my output:
24301-Manufacture of man-made fibres [this class includes manufacture of artificial or synthetic filament and non-filament fibres.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well escape them.

```
[a-zA-Z\d\s\)\(\]\[\.-]+
```

Comment: I have one more requirement in which my output is |Term Loan-amount or |Bill Purchase / Discounting (Inland)-amount and so on .should accept only in this fashion. can you please help me